# Syntax error trying to write a SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL is definitely not my strong point. I know it just well enough to get by. What I never managed to really learn well was how to use joins. I could never get conditional statements to work with joins and I have no idea why. So I figured I would figure it out. I'm making a private news feed, and this is my sql to fetch from the db

```
SELECT * FROM feed
WHERE INNER JOIN friends ON feed.user = friends.user1
WHERE friends.user2 = ? AND day = ?
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

The error that the PDO statement returns is:

- 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN friends ON feed.user = friends.user1 WHERE friends.user2 =' at line 1'

The line works fine by itself, if you get rid of that extra condition afterwards of 'AND day = ?' but it doesn't work the way it is written now. So this statement works

```
SELECT * FROM feed
INNER JOIN friends ON feed.user = friends.user1
WHERE friends.user2 = ?
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

My question is how do I add that 'AND day = ?' into the statement the right way?

Comment: `FROM * WHERE INNER JOIN` is not correct SQL statement.

Comment: You cannot use inner join in a where clause

Comment: remove the first where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM feed 
INNER JOIN friends ON feed.user = friends.user1 
WHERE friends.user2 = ? AND feed.day = ? 
ORDER BY feed.id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: That worked! just needed to add the table names to the where clause. THanks!